# For Cognos 11.1.7 Trying to figure out the syntax for a macro prompt where I can set the default to be all members

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

Cognos 11.1.7
Need help with syntax on a macro prompt so the default can be to select all members

Here is a simple example that works

```
set([Generic].[Groups].[Location].[Location] -> ?Location?)
```

If I wanted to hard code a value I could use this as a slicer

```
[Generic].[Groups].[Location].[Location]->[all].[1]
```

What is the syntax for creating a macro prompt with a default of all members?
i.e. instead of ?Location?
Something like this:

```
#Prompt('Location', 'token', '[all]')#
```

or maybe like

```
#Prompt('Location', 'memberuniquename', '[all]')#
```

Open to using different techniques (filter, set, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Fill in the default text parameter of the prompt macro.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.2.0?topic=macros-mandatory-optional-prompts
"**DefaultText**

This optional parameter is the text to be used by default. If a value is specified, the prompt is optional.

If you use a space and no values are provided in the Prompt Value dialog box, a Where clause is usually not generated.

If you use text and no values are provided in the Prompt Value dialog box, a Where clause is usually generated using the default value.

Ensure that the text you provide results in a valid SQL statement."

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/using-prompt-macro-optional-andor-required

You can also set a property in the filter in FM to make it optional.

Answer (score 1):

Both

```
#Prompt('Location', 'memberuniquename', '[Generic].[Groups].[Location].[Location]->[all].[1]')#
```

and

```
#Prompt('Location', 'token', '[Generic].[Groups].[Location].[Location]->[all].[1]')#
```

should work.  You also have the option to set a default value on the actual prompt object.